# Running python script from SSIS

Tags: python, ssis

I am trying to run Python script from SSIS but I am getting the below error
[image]

[image]

I have also tried using unwell_v2.py and that also gives me the error  "The process exit code was 1 while the expected was 0"

Answer (score 2):

exit code 2 error went away by changing the argument file to .py

and exit code 1 meant that there was some issue with the python script in my case. So I ran the python script independently using spyder and fixed it. It ran perfectly after that.